# ANTLR4: no viable alternative at input error

Tags: antlr, pascal, antlr4

Im using a cut down version of a pascal grammar to create a compiler which converts pascal to javascript, however i keep running into this error

```
line 3:4 no viable alternative at input 'PROCEDURE'
line 3:38 extraneous input ':' expecting {'END', ';'}
line 5:4 no viable alternative at input 'VAR'
```

The following is the relevant parts of my Grammar:

```
grammar pascal;

program
: programHeading ('INTERFACE')?
  block
  DOT
;

programHeading
: 'PROGRAM' identifier (LPAREN identifierList RPAREN)? SEMI
| 'UNIT' identifier SEMI
;

identifier
: IDENT
;

block
: ( labelDeclarationPart
  | constantDefinitionPart
  | typeDefinitionPart
  | variableDeclarationPart
  | procedureAndFunctionDeclarationPart
  | usesUnitsPart
  | 'IMPLEMENTATION'
  )*
   | compoundStatement
;
procedureAndFunctionDeclarationPart
: procedureOrFunctionDeclaration SEMI
;

procedureOrFunctionDeclaration
: procedureDeclaration
| functionDeclaration
;

procedureDeclaration
: 'PROCEDURE'  identifier (formalParameterList)? SEMI
  ( block | directive )
;

functionDeclaration
: 'FUNCTION' identifier (formalParameterList)? COLON resultType SEMI
  ( block | directive )
;

compoundStatement
: 'BEGIN'
statements
  'END'
;

statements
: statement ( SEMI statement )*
;

statement
: label COLON unlabelledStatement
| unlabelledStatement
;
```

im using antlr-4.5-complete and was just hoping someone could shed some light on this.

This is the program im trying to compile:

```
PROGRAM Lesson1_PROGRAM3;
BEGIN
PROCEDURE DrawLine(X : Integer; Y : Integer);

VAR
    Num1, Num2, Sum : Integer;

BEGIN
    Write('Input number 1:');
    Readln(Num1);
    Writeln('Input number 2:');
    Readln(Num2);
    Sum := Num1 + Num2;
    Writeln(Sum);
    Readln;

    IF Sel = '1' THEN
    BEGIN
        Total := N1 + N2;
        Write('Press any key TO continue...');
        Readkey;
        GOTO 1;
    END;

    FOR Counter := 1 TO 7 DO
        writeln('for loop');
    Readln;
END;
END.
```

Comment: Your `BEGIN` on second line is a `compoundStatement`. So, the `PROCEDURE` is the start of a `statement` rule. Your `statement` rule is not present in the grammar, but I don't think you are going back to a `procedureDeclaration` from `statement`.

Comment: Start with a valid pascal program to test ? This one isn't.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort could you possibly tell me whats wrong with the program? i was given it and told its valid

Comment: @Mephy okay, ive added the statement rule, could you possibly elaborate?

Comment: @Antlr the grammar is still incomplete, but it looks like the error is `BEGIN PROCEDURE` not being a valid string in the language described by the grammar. Try to find a way to derive it manually and you'll see.

Comment: Obviously your "cut down grammar" is not done right. Instead of guessing and readding back what you cut out before, start again with the full Pascal grammar. You will need it anyway.

Comment: begin procedure is not valid pascal. The block of the program/unit does not enclose the procedures/functions. It comes after them program (procedures) begin (mainprogram) end.